# Spring task not running parallel

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to have my Application doing things parrallel but it's currently not working but I don't know why.
As background information I have multiple scheduled task, that where scheduled with a ThreadPoolTaskScheduler, which I have definded as follows:

```
    @Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler
            = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(1000);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix(
            "GAXThreadPoolTaskScheduler");
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

I also have a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor which executes a task, after I publish an event (the observer runs this task). The event is published by an other Task, I call the task "Task1".
The SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor ist configurated as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class AsynchronousSpringEventsConfig {
    @Bean(name = "applicationEventMulticaster")
    public ApplicationEventMulticaster simpleApplicationEventMulticaster() {
        SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster eventMulticaster =
                new SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster();

        eventMulticaster.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        return eventMulticaster;
    }
}
```

Now current behavior is as follows:

```
                           :Task1:
                             |
                             |
                             |
                             |
      [condition for one Object is true publish the event]
                             |
                             |
 [condition for another Object is true publish the event second time]
                             |
                             |
                      :finish Task1:
                   :handle first event:
                             |
           [time passes due to it waits on rest response]
                             |
                :finish handle first event:
                  :handle second event:
                             |
           [time passes due to it waits on rest response]
                             |
                :finish handle second event:
                          :Task1:
                             |
                             |
                           .....
```

But thats not the behaviour I want. I want a behaviour like this:

```
      :Task1:
         |
         |
         |
         |
 [p. first event]           
         |                        :handle first event:
         |                                  |                   
 [p. second event]                 [wait for response]          :handle second event:
         |                                  |                              |
         |                     :finish handle first event:         [wait for response] 
  :finish Task1:                                                           |
      :Task1:                                                   :finish handle second event:
         |
         |
      .......
```

See the two graphics as a timeline the more down it gets the more time passed.

#### My question now is

Can anyone tell my how i can obtain the desired behaviour?

PS: If you need more information I will gladly provide it to you

### EDIT

You can find the log file [here](https://pastebin.com/i2kPm9Qi). In the log you can see on the basis of the timestamps that the tasks are not running parallel. The log is also where I determine that the task aren't running parallel.

Task1 I start as follows:

```
 private void startTask1(Company company) {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler executor = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        executor.initialize();

        Task1 task1 = new Task1(company, articleSizeService, tradeService, eventPublisher, taskExecutor, optionsService);
            ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task1 , 1000);
        
    }
```

The class that calls this method is also a Task that is executed by this:

```
  @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor
                = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix(
                "ThreadPoolTaskExecutor");
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for such detailied question. How did you determine that your tasks won't execute parallel. How do you start an actual task?

Comment: @Marcinek I edited the post. I hope these are the information you needed.

Comment: You do not use the threadPoolTaskExecuter. By creating a ThredPoolTaskSceduler on your own, it is not handelt by spring thus it won't be executed asynchrone. @Nimal see here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/